# Corrupted Japanese words becomes Chinese words

Tags: unicode

I have this problem when a song's details becomes gibberish Chinese language. For example:

トランスルーセント becomes 僩儔儞僗儖乕僙儞僩

This usually happens to downloaded songs. I analyzed the unicode and they seem to differ at around 8k. What is changing the unicodes? My friend downloaded the same file with no problem.

Comment: Maybe your internet has been hacked by The Chinese Government?

Answer (score 3):

The sequence of bytes:

```
83 67 83 89 83 93 83 58 83 8b 81 5b 83 5a 83 93 83 67
```

Can be interpreted using the Shift-JIS encoding (on Windows, code page 932) as “トランスルーセント”, or using the GB encoding (on Windows, code page 936) as “僩儔儞僗儖乕僙儞僩”. If a Windows machine encounters a series of bytes like that without any signalling to tell it which encoding is in use, it will choose its “default code page”, which depends on the setting in the Control Panel Regional Options “Language for non-Unicode applications” field. If set to Japanese you see “トランスルーセント”, if Chinese you get “僩儔儞僗儖乕僙儞僩”, if Western European you get “ƒgƒ‰ƒ“ƒXƒ‹�[ƒZƒ“ƒg” (classic mojibake).

To avoid this happening as an application author you should use Unicode strings and Unicode-safe encodings like UTF-8 and UTF-16 to store data. To avoid this happening as an end-user you should use applications and formats that support Unicode. If you are downloading a random MP3, of course, you don't get much say on what the application that encoded it did and you will have to put up with it.

It's not clear what exact sequence of events you are describing in your question and what you are comparing that differs. If you are comparing MP3 files be aware that some highly antisocial media player applications decide to write to the ID3 tags when they play a file, which may change it in arbitrary ways.